# Does pandas 0.13.0 support Teradata server? I am trying to write a dataframe object to teradata using a pyodbc connection

Tags: python, pandas, teradata, pyodbc

Does pandas 0.13.0 support Teradata ODBC connection? I am trying to create a table in teradata from a pandas dataframe object using a pyodbc connection.

The code I am using is below:

```
import pyodbc
import pandas

connection=pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={Teradata};dbcname=dbcname;uid=userid;pwd=password;databasename=db_name;quietmode=yes',autocommit=True)
data=pandas.read_csv(data_file)
data.to_sql('table_name',con=connection,flavor=None)
```

I am getting a NotImplementedError.

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 2):

This is not supported in pandas 0.13.0 (flavor cannot be None, only 'sqlite' and 'mysql' are supported).

In more recent versions of pandas (starting with pandas 0.14), the database support has been expanded through the use of SQLAlchemy. So now, all database flavors that are supported by sqlalchemy can be used in `to_sql` (see [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html#io-sql)).

For the case of a teradata server, I am not sure (no experience with this). The only requirement to use it with `to_sql` is that you can connect to it with an sqlalchemy engine. However, I don't directly find something about that.